# Commuting property of fundamental matrices ΦA = AΦ

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

This theorem had no provided proof and I would like to know how they got to it. I would appreciated any help you can offer of explaining how they arrived to this conclusion..

**Theorem 4.34**

If $\Phi$ is a normalized fundamental matrix of $\dot X =AX$ at $t_0$, then

$A\Phi(t) = \Phi(t)A$

Comment: Supposedly $A$ is constant? Then essentially because $\Phi(t)=e^{tA}$ is in the algebra generated by $A$. There might be more elementary arguments.

Comment: If you can use $\Phi(t)\Phi(s)=\Phi(t+s)$, then take the $s$-derivative at $s=0$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I am still not getting it. I tried the derivative as you suggested, but unable to switch the $A$ and $\Phi$ around

Comment: You get $Φ(t)\dot Φ(0)=\dot Φ(t)$, now insert the ODE and $Φ(0)=I$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, thanks again, and sorry to be a burden, but this only works for $t_0 = 0$? and not any $t_0$?

Comment: For autonomous systems $t_0=0$ is the canonical choice. What do you understand under "normalized" fundamental matrix?

Comment: @LutzLehmann for normalized fundamental matrix, at $t_0$ ,$\Phi(t) = \Phi(t_0) =I$

Comment: Then you need to adapt the group formula, $Φ(t+s)=Φ(t)Φ(t_0+s)$ or so. Then the property still follows from the derivative at $s=0$.